# dynamically create JS objects based on html text content

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

***i.e.***    `<span id="username">Fred Randall</span>`

Say; I have an html element `"username"` with changing text content within it. Which is the logged in users name.

I would like to each time there is new text content within this, or each time it changes with a new logged in `username`;

I would like to dynamically create a JavaScript object using that user's name. Either as the Object name itself, or as the Object `[key]` name.

So each time the text content within `id="username"` changes to something else; *i.e.* a new username => use that username text content to create a new object using the name.

***i.e.***

```
myObject[FredRandall] { 
    field1: Ablah;
    field2: Bblah;
    field3: Cblah;
}
```

or just:

```
FredRandall { 
    field1: Ablah;
    field2: Bblah;
    field3: Cblah;
}
```

Comment: Yes you can: just use `MutationObserver` to do that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: That content would change because of some Javascript executing, right? Wouldn’t it make more sense to hook into that than observing an HTML element? Unless you have no control over the script somehow…

Answer (score -1):

```js
var name = document.getElementById('username').innerHTML;

var obj = {
  username: name
}

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<span id="username">Fred Randall</span>
```

Comment: That's a property though; not the Object name nor Objecy [key] name?

Comment: With "key" you mean `"Fred Randall": somevalue`?

Comment: I think you would want to use `Map` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). It is a set of objects and each object has a key. I created a fiddle for that (https://jsfiddle.net/qjo31yrv/)